# Substitue config with scopes

Tags: java, scala, playframework, typesafe, typesafe-config

i have a lot of properties so i wanted to reuse as much as possible.
Therefore i have defined generic object :

```
db-user-generic{
  db.host = mymachine

  #mssql or oracle
  db.type = oracle
  db.username = user
  db.password= password

  mssql {
    port = 1433
    name = None
    url = "jdbc:sqlserver://"${?host}":"${?port}
  }
  oracle {
    port = 1521
    serviceNameOrSID = ORCL
    url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@"${?host}":"${?port}":"${?serviceNameOrSID}
  }
}
```

the problem with this code is for example : 
"jdbc:oracle:thin:@"${?host}":"**${?port}**":"${?serviceNameOrSID}

port is not defined for this but db-user-generic.mssql.port is defined.
so now the inned property should know what it is the exact location , which means it could not be reused like this :

```
my-db= ${db-user-generic}
my-db=  {
      mssql {
         port= 1111
      }
}
```

since the url attribute should be overriden too because he reference to db-user-generic.mssql.port and not to my-db.mssql.port

anyone has idea how this could be resolved?